# CSS some parts doesn't refresh

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, refresh

Here my css:

```
   @CHARSET "UTF-8";

.commandLinks {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px; /* 20px makes room for your background image */
    /*border: 1px solid #aaa; */

}

.commandLinks .create {
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: red;
}

.commandLinks .vote {
    color: blue;
}

.commandLinks .link {
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16;
}

.button {
    margin-right: 10;
    margin-left: 5;
}
```

I tried different things, refreshing browser CTRL - F5, restarting eclipse, etc.
But font-size: 16; or

```
margin-right: 10;
        margin-left: 5;
```

doesn't apper anyway.
For example when I added font-weight: bold; it appears without no problems.

My jsf code:

```
    <div id="links" class="commandLinks" >
    <h:link styleClass="link" outcome="Answers">answers</h:link>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong or how can I refresh css ?

Comment: Tried putting `16px` instead of 16?

Comment: I'm posting this as an answer with a reference to a similar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 16px instead of 16. Technically font sizes (without px) have a range from 1 to 7. Hence 16 is invalid. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819079/how-to-convert-font-size-10-to-px)

Comment: Yeah. You need to use 20px 2em 10% etc, or in the case of zero, since it's always just 0, you can leave it without a unit.