# What is the pixel size of the element specified in the html tag font

Tags: html

For example:

```
<font size="4">Sometext</font>
<font size="5">Sometext</font>
```

How can i calculate pixel size of this elements?

Comment: What @j08691 is trying to say is that the `font` element is non-standard and doesn't make an appearance in any recent HTML specification... so you shouldn't use it... ever. http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/font

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819079/how-to-convert-font-size-10-to-px#answer-819121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pixel size is dependant upon what your browser currently uses as it's default size. This is usually in pts, which can be converted to pixels to get your answer. Check your browser settings for this.

The size attribute of font tag works as follows:
A number from 1 to 7 that defines the size of the text. Browser default is 3.

Note: The font tag itself is deprectated, for compatibility  tag should be used instead, example:

```
<span style='font-size:10px;'>My Text</span
```