# Make jquery button invisible after is clicked to toggle div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

The code I am using is for toggling button to reveal a div is below:

```
<button href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$('#target').toggle();">
    <b><font size="6">LOAD MORE</font></b>
</button>
```

I want it to become invisible once it is clicked to reveal div - I understand to see it page must be reloaded. I am not sure what to add.

Comment: should be visible now.

Comment: $('#target').hide() ????

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/qp13zn9s/1/

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<button id="theButton">ClickMe</button>
<div id="theDiv" style="display:none;"><p>So text</p></div>
```

And here is the JavaScript using JQuery:

```
$("#theButton").click(function(){
    $("#theButton").hide();
    $("#theDiv").show();
})
```

Comment: Please reference element in callback with `$(this)` - much better

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. The guidance worked perfectly.

Comment: @user3931756 , be sure to mark the check under the voting arrows to show that this answer helped you. This will help future users.

Answer (score 1):

Separate out your event handler and HTML for clarity:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mybutton">
    <strong><span style="font-size: 2em">LOAD MORE</span></strong>
</button>
```

Then jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.mybutton').click(function(e) {
        // do stuff
        $('#target').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

1. I've [replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819121/2812842) the font tag with a span ([font tag is not supported in HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp)).
2. `href` is an attribute for `a` tags, you're using a `button` so define the type of it instead of the href.
3. Use `.toggle()` if you have the possibility to show this button again, or if the div can be shown by another method other than this button. If it's only a one way hide on each page view, a simple `.show()` will do since it can't be hidden again.

Answer (score 0):

its really easy use this code first add another id or class for your button because by choosing btn btn-danger all btn btn-danger buttons will get hidden 
for example if you add id "loadmore" your code will be something like this

```
    <button href="#" id="loadmore" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$('#target').toggle();">
        <b><font size="6">LOAD MORE</font></b>
    </button>

<script>
    $('#loadmore').click(function(){

    ////// code to show more

    $('#loadmore').hide(); //// u can use other functions too

    });
    </script>
```

any way i recommend you to use the code bellow (its clearer)

```
<style>
    button#loadmore{
        font-size: 60px;
        font-style: bold;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#loadmore').click(function(){
            $('#target').toggle();

            $('#loadmore').hide(); //// u can use other functions too

        });

    });
</script>

<button href="#" id="loadmore" class="btn btn-danger"> LOAD MORE </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("button.exampleClass").click(function() {
$(this).hide();
$("#target").toggle();
});
});

</script>
```

Don't forget to call jquery before you use the code above.

And you html

```
 <button href="#" class="btn btn-danger exampleClass">
 <b><font size="6">LOAD MORE</font></b>
 </button>
```

Comment: Attaching this event handler to every btn-danger button in the document is probably a bad suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following [JS fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/akht9sq3/) `code reference` for your better understanding & you can play with it.

In your example you haven't given code for target button but in the above linked example you can see that.

Here is my code::

```
<button href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$('#target').toggle();">
    <b><font size="6">LOAD MORE</font></b>
</button>

<button id="target">Target</button>
```

Comment: i've not posted this answer but i just dont understand why someone marked it as unhelpful ?