# Convert font tag (size attribute) to css

Tags: html, css

How would I convert the size attribute of the font tag:

```
<font size="3">Example</font>
```

to css? for example

```
.example{
 font-size: ?px;
}
```

In other words, how many pixels does the size attribute refer to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't an easy question, and the real answer is **IT DEPENDS**.

See, the HTML sizes aren't a real size, but a somehow random size.  The SIZE attribute allows you to set your font to an abstract size ranging from 1 to 7. The exact type size corresponding to each of these values is left to your browser. You can't be sure, for example, that SIZE=4 will give you a 12 point typeface; you know only that SIZE=4 will be bigger than SIZE=3.

Thus, what you see at 12px in one browser will be 13px or 14 px in another browser. There's a very [interesting test made by SO user Eugene Yokota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819079/how-to-convert-font-size-10-to-px) where you can see the approximate rendering of fonts translated to em:

```
<font size=1>- font size 1</font><br>
<span style="font-size:0.63em">- font size: 0.63em</span><br>

<font size=2>- font size 2</font><br>
<span style="font-size: 0.82em">- font size: 0.82em</span><br>

<font size=3>- font size 3</font><br>
<span style="font-size: 1.0em">- font size: 1.0em</span><br>

<font size=4>- font size 4</font><br>
<span style="font-size: 1.13em">- font size: 1.13em</span><br>

<font size=5>- font size 5</font><br>
<span style="font-size: 1.5em">- font size: 1.5em</span><br>

<font size=6>- font size 6</font><br>
<span style="font-size: 2em">- font size: 2em</span><br>

<font size=7>- font size 7</font><br>
<span style="font-size: 3em">- font size: 3em</span><br>
```

But this is still somehow subjective and of course doesn't answer the fixed (pixels) question. However, you can use the table above to translate to pixels as a guide:

```
Font=1: 10px
Font=2: 13px
Font=3: 16px
Font=4: 18px
Font=5: 24px
Font=6: 32px
Font=7: 48px
```

Now, the thing is that once you have your pixels in line, you really don't need to worry, so as long as you define something like `"font-size:12px"` all browsers will (should) render a font with 12px height

If you're interested in differences between Font Size tag rendering between browsers, yu can take a look to this [link with may examples](http://style.cleverchimp.com/font_size_intervals/altintervals.html#cc)

Comment: Much better answer then mine! ;) +1

Comment: ah, didn't see yours until you mentioned and I was going to upvote it and I couldn't because it was already deleted. It was good too, shame you deleted it because for what I saw it had some additional info on an issue that looks pretty shallow yet still doesn't have a definitive answer

Answer (score 1):

"3" is "default", so the closest equivalent would be to omit any `font-size` specification, or use `font-size: 1 rem`.

A reasonable assumption is that '2' corresponds to 'smaller', '4' to 'larger', etc.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert `<font>` to font-size in pixels, as the font size of the font tag varies in between the base font size.
It can be done in em, as posted in this SO question, [How to convert <font size="10"> to px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819079/how-to-convert-font-size-10-to-px).
The chart below came from @EugeneYokota's answer there:

> - font size 1
>  -
>   font size: 0.63em
>
> - font size 2
>  - font size: 0.82em
>
> - font size 3
>  -
>   font size: 1.0em
>
> - font size 4
>  - font size: 1.13em
>
> - font size 5
>  -
>   font size: 1.5em
>
> - font size 6
>  -
>   font size: 2em
>
> - font size 7
>  -
>   font size: 3em

[This font-size converter might be helpful](http://pxtoem.com/)
The font tags, font sizes are relative, meaning they change depending on the base font size.
 [This article explains it in more detail](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_font_size_code.cfm)

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<p class="example">Paragraph Text</p>
```

CSS

```
p.example{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

With that said, you should read into more scalable CSS so that you are not targeting a single paragraph.

Comment: Why do you think that the "3" as the value of the `size` attribute of the (obsolete) `font` tag would necessarily be equal to `12px`, which is what the OP was asking?

Comment: Merely providing an example from which the OP could work from.