# What is the default unit if the specified font size has none?

Tags: css, html4

I'm converting HTML4 to HTML5, and I have this:

```
<font face="Verdana" size="2">
```

The above is no longer supported in HTML5. What value and unit does the font size above map to in CSS?

Comment: Whatever the browser' default is...usually it 16px but some use 14px. That's why we generally recommend a CSS Reset.

Comment: Based on a base of 16px, size 2 will be 13px. As Paulie says, it's browser dependant but for most this is the case. https://jsfiddle.net/90qvv63d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the **Font** tag had 7 degrees of freedom. You can specify a value between 1 and 7. 7 is largest and 3 is default

[Font Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_size.asp)

In CSS you have the **font-size** property, also 7 degrees of freedom, the constants for it are not numeric, and  **medium** (which is the 3rd value) is the default.

<kbd>FONT Tag</kbd>   <kbd>font-size CSS</kbd>
<kbd>N/A</kbd>             <kbd>xx-small</kbd>         
       <kbd>1</kbd>          <kbd>x-small</kbd>           
       <kbd>2</kbd>          <kbd>small</kbd>              
       <kbd>3</kbd>          <kbd>medium</kbd>          <kbd>(default values)</kbd>
       <kbd>4</kbd>          <kbd>large</kbd>              
       <kbd>5</kbd>          <kbd>x-large</kbd>           
       <kbd>6</kbd>          <kbd>xx-large</kbd>         
       <kbd>7</kbd>          <kbd>N/A</kbd>

[CSS font-size Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp)

So if you consider that the default values do not match up exactly betewen both standards, then we can assume that the standards are slightly different, without 1:1 mapping or meaning. Your value of 2, might be **small** and it might not. I do think that is probably is **small** though.

You will discover that other factors are coming into play with CSS, and you will generally discover other discrepancies that prevent a direct conversion between the **Font** tag and the CSS properties. You might be safe on this one, though, as these values are defined as "absolute sizes".

see: [It Depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897264/convert-font-tag-size-attribute-to-css)
see: [Size to px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819079/how-to-convert-font-size-10-to-px)

Comment: Google Chrome translates it to **small** not **x-small**.

Comment: thanks, I edit it...so its going to be hard to directly convert the 2, since they do not map 1:1

Comment: They are not mapped directly. `font-size` has one smaller value and `font` has one bigger value. That's all, they are offset and extremes do not match. Just make side-by-side comparison.

Comment: thanks, I think things like inheritance might come into play, that cause problems with planning and conversion, too.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nicely comprehensive answer!