# Convert HTML's font size attribute to CSS font-size attribute

Tags: java, html, css, fonts, flying-saucer

My question is pretty much a duplicate question from [Convert font tag (size attribute) to css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897264/convert-font-tag-size-attribute-to-css)

I see the answers there are from 2014.  So I wasn't sure to continue to ask there or to make this new question.  But I'm running into the same issue and wondered if there is a solution to this since then apart from Devin's answer in that link above.

Within a Java application I'm trying to parse some HTML lines of code and then set some font values programmatically as CSS.

I have a simple font output that has the text font size set to 6.

```
<font id="test" face="Calibri" size="6" color="#000000">Hello World</font>
```

It displays fine, but as mentioned above I'm trying to parse out the face, size and color attributes and set that as CSS as such:

```
<style>

#test {
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Calibri, Times, serif;
   font-size: 6px;    
}
</style>
```

When this CSS text gets displayed the "Hello World" text is considerably smaller.

I understand that within the CSS I have the font-size unit as px, but I can't find online what unit is the HTML font size attribute to do the conversion.

What is the unit of the HTML font size attribute? so I know how to programmatically parse it and create the appropriate CSS values?

Comment: The attribute sizer for font is not working anymore on HTML5, you need to use CSS instead. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_size.asp

Comment: @AlvaroAlves understood.  But this HTML/CSS issue I have will be rendered in a Java application and not on a web browser.

Comment: oh, i see, then you can take the em values and use this conversor: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp

Comment: `size=6` refers to pt size - maybe `font-size: 6pt` (instead of px) for the CSS.

Comment: on the box "Convert EM to PX:" you put e.g. 0.63em => then its will be converted to Result: 10.08px - And have a table with some conversions there

Comment: @AlvaroAlves Thanks for the link.  Unfortunately the issue isn't trying to convert from pixels to em or vice versa.  It's trying to figure out what unit is the html font size attribute, so I know how to convert to CSS font-size attribute.

Comment: @AndrewS thanks I'll give that a try

Comment: one last note: "Pixel is a static measurement, while percent and EM are relative measurements. The size of an EM or percent depends on its parent. If the text size of body is 16 pixels, then 150% or 1.5 EM will be 24 pixels (1.5 * 16). Look at CSS Units for more measurement units."

Comment: Sorry, "this will be rendered in Java application" isn't enough to explain why you are using an element that hasn't been in the HTML spec since 1998. It wasn't removed with HTML5, it was removed with HTML4.01, twenty years ago. No modern or even somewhat old Java application with a web renderer would still use this.

Answer (score 2):

There's some mystery here, because no sane Java application today would support this, and no one writing HTML today should even know that this tag ever existed... it's not been a thing for almost twenty years: no HTML standard has had a `<font>` element since HTML 4.01, released in 1999.

The last HTML standard that allowed the `<font>` element was HTML 3.2, so let us consult [the HTML3.2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/) from 1997:

> Font sizes are given in terms of a scalar range defined by the user agent with no direct mapping to point sizes etc.

So you are, unfortunately, entirely out of luck. There is literally no way to tell which actual point or pixel size a font "should" be using, given the HTML3.2 `size` attribute for the `<font>` element. You might be able to find out what specific versions of specific browsers on specific operating systems used to support back when HTML 3.2 was still a thing, but that information will be useless for any other OS, and any other browser, and even any other version for that same browser on the same OS.

It's one of the main reasons that styling attributes were taken out of the HTML specification entirely, with styling instructions left (almost) exclusively for CSS to handle.

With all of that said: what crazy Java code are you working with that you can use a `<font>` element without errors, or at the very least warnings about markup that hasn't existed for two decades?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty rusty on Java and I don't know how you're parsing/declaring your class properties so this may not apply... Might get you going though

```
//Make an array with the sizes and their equivalents. Probably a more elegant way to accomplish this 
var sizes = [['6', '2em'], ['7', '3em'], /*etc. Follow pattern from example you provided*/]
Document myDoc = parse(myHtml);
Element myEl = myDoc.select("font").first();
String mySize = myEl.attr("size");
String fontSize = "";

//Also not so elegant
for(int i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++){
    if(mySize.equals(sizes[i][0])){
       fontSize = sizes[i][1];
    }
}
```