# No more content will display below DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add the a footer image below these two messages. The bottom one is transparent and anything that I add below "message 2" goes behind instead of below it, How do I keep editing below these?

In theory adding even just some text like

```html
<p>hello</p>
```

should appear below. It shows behind the message 2 div and doesn't allow me to actually edit below, it edits behind. How would I go about fixing this?

```html
<style>
 body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message1 {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.message2 {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: ##6d1a76;
  }
</style>

<style>
.messagetext {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
</style>


<div class="message1">

<div class="messagetext">
<p class="Roboto"><a href="URL">URL TEXT</a></p>
</div>

</div>

<div class="message2">

<div class="messagetext">
<font size="3" color="#ffffff">
<p class="Roboto">TEXT</p>
</font>
</div>

<div>
<br>

<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0%;
   width: 100%;
   
}
</style>

<!--Footer-->
<div class="footer" src="FOOTER IMAGE" width="80%" alt="Footer"> </div>
<br>
```

If you try adding text below it just shows next to the existing text, I need it to show below.

Comment: The `<font>` element is obsolete. Do not use that. I'm not even sure if your usage of it is valid either.

Answer (score 1):

Your footer has `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0%;`, so it is at the bottom of the page (I gave it a height and made its background yellow to make it visible, BTW an `src` attribute in the footer DIV won't produce an image).

The `position: fixed`  also takes it out of the rest of the document flow, so whatever come * after* the footer will simply follow whatever is *before*  the footer.

Additionally, you had a few minor mistakes/typos in your code - unclosed tags both in HTML and CSS rules. I split it in CSS and HTML to make it clearer in my snippet below

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message1 {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.message2 {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100px;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6d1a76;
}

.messagetext {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffffaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="message1">

  <div class="messagetext">
    <p class="Roboto"><a href="URL">URL TEXT</a></p>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="message2">

  <div class="messagetext">
    <font size="3" color="#ffffff">
      <p class="Roboto">TEXT</p>
    </font>
  </div>



  <!--Footer-->
  <div class="footer" src="FOOTER IMAGE" width="80%" alt="Footer"> </div>
  
  <p>THIS IS BELOW THE FOOTER IN THE HTML CODE, but above it in the document flow</p>
```

Comment: The errors were because I've changed it so much. I'd put the div and the image source in the same <> rather than separately, it works now. Thanks for your response.